# Capistrano 3: use server custom variable in task

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I have multi-stage multi-server setup and in my task I need to use server name
e.g. in stagin.rb I have:

```
set :stage, :staging
# Define servers
server 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app}, name: 'app1'
server 'xxx.xx.xx.yyy', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app}, name: 'app2'
```

and I want to use that "name" variable in my task:

```
task :configure do
  on roles(:app), in: :parallel do
  # how do I get server name here?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to return the hostname / IP, then it will be

```
task :configure do
  on roles(:app), in: :parallel do |server|
    p server.hostname # server hostname should be in here
  end
end
```

If you would like to access custom properties, like `:name` in this particular case, they are stored in the `properties` hash of the `server` configuration object: just use `server.properties.name` instead of `server.hostname`.

Comment: this actually returns the name of a task :) if I change variable name in server definition to "appname" and try "puts server.appname" I get "Undefined method 'appname' for <Rake::Task ..."

Comment: @a.yastreb Sorry, my bad, misplaced parameter. I corrected the answer, thanks for the heads-up.