# server properties in loops in Capistrano

Tags: capistrano3

I am new to Capistrano.

I need to get the server properties in tasks using a loop. I am using this code:

```
server 'IP_address', user: 'root', password: 'pass', roles: %w{web}, database: 'production1'

server 'IP_address', user: 'root', password: 'pass', roles: %w{web}, database: 'production2'


task :backup_FilesDatabaseServerfiles do
  on roles (:web) do |h|
    puts h.database 
  end
end
```

How can I fetch database options in the above task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
task :backup_FilesDatabaseServerfiles do
  on roles :web do |server|
    p server.properties.database
  end
end
```

Per [Capistrano 3: use server custom variable in task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233873/capistrano-3-use-server-custom-variable-in-task)